# How to use Moment.js instead of New data()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, momentjs

How do I use Moment.js in the following code？

```
Meteor.methods({
  'Sessions.add'({ id, text, startDate, duration }) {
    const endDate = new Date();
    const durationMinutesInMillis = duration * 60 * 1000;
    endDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + durationMinutesInMillis);
    if (duration < 1) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('Duration cannot be 0 or lower');
    } else {
      Sessions.collection.insert({ id, text, startDate, endDate });
    }
  },
});
```

Expected Result Format:

```
"yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00"
```

I don't know how to replace setTime() and getTime()

Comment: Moment is deprecated and shouldn't be used for new code

Answer (score 0):

The moment.js library is deprecated, you should not use it anymore. Consider modern libraries like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/). But I know, if you have to support legacy systems, then often there is no other choice.

More important, you should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Having said all this, the solution would be this one:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'Sessions.add'({ id, text, startDate, duration }) {
    const endDate =  moment(startDate).add(duration, 'minutes');
    if (duration < 1) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('Duration cannot be 0 or lower');
    } else {
      Sessions.collection.insert({ id, text, startDate, endDate.toDate() });
    }
  },
});
```